# unable to find such element

Tags: c#, selenium

trying to search element by id but showing as no such element found

```
IWebElement elemCaseOptions_exe = ThreeWChromeDriver.FindElementById("incident|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.HomepageGrid.incident.DocumentTemplate");
```

Comment: Add the relevant html

Comment: Do you know if there is an element with that id?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
ThreeWChromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id("PUT_HERE_ID"));
```

Comment: _"findElement(By.id()) requires you to created your own By.id instance. findElementById(String) is a helper function that will generate the By.id"_ so these are likely to be identical.